# Need help to put dynamic value on dynamic field using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm making a simple checkout form where in the form user only need to input the code of the product, type of product and the quantity of the product they want to purchase and then using jQuery calculating the total price based on the quantity amount they want to purchase and showing it on the total field.

```
<div id="startcart">
    <div id="cart0">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
          <input type="text" name="kodeproduk[]" value="" placeholder="Kode Produk" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-25">
          <input type="text" name="tipeproduk[]" value="" placeholder="Tipe Handphone" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-25">
          <input type="number" name="jumlah[]" placeholder="0" class="form-control jumlah" min="0"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-25">
          <input type="number" name="total[]" value="" placeholder="Total" class="form-control total" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div id="cart1"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is, right now the total price is only shown on the first fields which is the parent fields and whenever i try to add more fields dynamically and changing the quantity, the total price value only counting the value based from the first fields but the total quantity counted perfect

I had trying to mapping the array and the qty array is working fine but not for the total array
Below are the jQuery script I had use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var i=1;
   $("#add_row").click(function(){
      b=i-1;
      var html = $(this).nextAll("#cart0").html();
      //console.log(html);
      //console.log(b);
      $('#cart'+i).html($('#cart'+b).html()).find('#cart'+b).html(i+1);
      $('#startcart').append('<div id="cart'+(i+1)+'"></div>');
      i++; 
   });
   $("#delete_row").click(function(){
      if(i>1){
        $("#cart"+(i-1)).html('');
        i--;
      }
      calc();
   });

   $('#startcart').on("keyup change", ".jumlah", function(){
      calc();
   });
   $('#tax').on('keyup change',function(){
      calc_total();
   });
});

function calc()
{   
    /*$("div#startcart").each(function() {
        //console.log($(this));
    });*/

    $('#startcart').each(function(i, element) {
        var html = $(this).html();
        console.log(html);
        var jumlah = $(".jumlah").map(function(){ return this.value}).get();
        console.log(jumlah);
        var total = $(".total").map(function(){ return this.value}).get();
        console.log(total);
        if(html!='')
        {
            var qty = $(".jumlah").val();
            //var qty = $(item).val();
            console.log("jumlah kuantiti "+qty);
            var price = 25000;
            //var totalprice = qty*price;
            //console.log(totalprice);
            $(".total").val(qty*price);

            calc_total();
        }
    });
}

function calc_total()
{
    total=0;
    jumlah=0;
    $('.total').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('.jumlah').each(function() {
        jumlah += parseInt($(this).val());
        console.log(jumlah);
    });
    var GrandTo = document.getElementById('GrandTotal');
    var GrandPro = document.getElementById('JumlahOrder');
    GrandTo.innerHTML = '<b>Rp '+total.toFixed(2)+'</b>';
    JumlahOrder.innerHTML = '<b> '+jumlah+'</b>';
}
```

If you need to replicate the problem, you can do it by visiting https://jsfiddle.net/boiler/7Lacn2mx/1

Comment: jQuery does not see the dom change is the reason perhaps.

Comment: fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c72ghupv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues:

```
$("#startcart").each(...
```

there's only one #startcart, so no need to `each` it - you want to `each` the `.cartN` inside, so change to:

```
$("#startcart>div").each(...
```

Next

```
$(".jumlah")...
```

will look at all `.jumlah` on the page, but you're wanting only the one within the current cart of the loop above, so change to:

```
$(".jumlah", this)...
```

Not sure what all the `.map value get()` is for, so change to:

```
var jumlah = $(".jumlah", this).val()
```

no need to get the current total, but left in

Make the same changes to setting the total:

```
$(".total", this).val(qty*price);
```

not sure you need the `html=` part, but left anyway

didn't look at `calc_total` as you said that was working

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c72ghupv/

Comment: wow, working great perfectly
thank you so much for your help bro :)

Comment: may i know the function of this code ?
from what my logic tell the code below will look inside #startcart, am i correct ?

    $("#startcart>div").each(...

Comment: `>` inside a selector means direct-child.  While `#startcart div` will find all divs at all levels below #startcart, you wouldn't want that, so `#startcart > div` is the same as `$("#startcart").children().filter("div")`